# Is it possible to set the value of promise to a object

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

So I have used `.then` to try and assign the value of promise to the object but I can't and now I tried a anonymous async function which isnt helping me.

````js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { setProps } from '../helpers/objectResponse.js';
if (!globalThis.fetch) {
    globalThis.fetch = fetch;
}

const wrapMe = (pokimon) => {
    let value;
    const getPokimon = async (pokimon) => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokimon.toLowerCase()}`);
    const response = await data.json();
    return response
    }

    (async () => {
        const data = await getPokimon(pokimon);
        return value = data
    })
    return value

}```
````

Comment: @zero298 what I'm trying is to return the value as string or object I dont a callback function

Comment: "*assign the value of promise to the object*" - which object? And where are you calling `wrapMe`? No, you will never achieve a method that synchronously returns the data. All you can do is return a promise. Deal with that in the location where you call the function.

Answer (score -1):

the wrapMe me function need to be async

Answer (score -1):

you must have to use callback or promise for ajax requests you cant simply call ajax and get its value for return

Return `data.json()` without using await so your promise will be returned to `getPokimon`

try doing this way

```js
function getPokimon(pokimon) {
    return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokimon.toLowerCase()}`).then(r=>r.json())
}

getPokimon("ditto").then(r=>{
    console.log(r)
})
```